# running a php script from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I am trying to add markers to a google map with coordinates being queried from a mysql database. the script is shown below, within a file named connection.php.

```php
$query = "SELECT site, latitude, longitude, pollution FROM pollution_monitoring.locations";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
    $site      = $row['site'];
    $latitude  = $row['latitude'];
    $longitude = $row['longitude'];
    $pollution = $row['pollution'];

    echo ("addMarker($latitude,$longitude,'<b>$site</b><br/>$pollution');\n");     
}
```

addMarker() is a JavaScript function that has been defined in the below file

```js
var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png",
    new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
var center = null;
var map = null;
var currentPopup;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    bounds.extend(pt);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pt,
        icon: icon,
        map: map
    });
    var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: info,
        maxWidth: 500
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        if (currentPopup != null) {
            currentPopup.close();
            currentPopup = null;
        }
        popup.open(map, marker);
        currentPopup = popup;
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
        map.panTo(center);
        currentPopup = null;
    });
}

function initialize() {
    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-29.335989, 27.483622999999966),
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        overviewMapControl: true,
        rotateControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    };
    $.get('connection.php');

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

the above script is to be used to load a google map and have to markers added to the map. I had thought the result of the php script (the addMarker function) would be ran  with  and have the markers added to the map, but that does not happen. the JavaScript is then included in a jsp file. The map loads, but no markers are added.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What does the rendered code look like?

Comment: A better way to do this would be to retrieve the markers as JSON. Use `json_encode` on the result array and look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15145021/488074) to see how to retrieve the markers as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite your php script to generate JSON data:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$query = "SELECT site,latitude,longitude,pollution FROM pollution_monitoring.locations";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$i = 0;
echo '[';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
    if ($i++ != 0) echo ',';
    echo json_encode($row);    
}
echo ']';
```

Then add the markers using JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON('connection.php', function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data[i]; i++) {
        addMarker(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude, "<b>" + data[i].site + "</b><br />" + data[i].pollution);
    }
});
```

Comment: I added the above code  to the php. when i run the php file i get
Parse error: parse error, expecting `')''

Comment: According to http://phpcodechecker.com/ there should be no syntax errors in the code above. However, I just noticed that the generated JSON array contains no commas. I'll fix that in a moment.