# Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined Google Maps JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, undefined

I am unable get the property of a JSON object to be read to create a marker from. In the past, I've used `feature.geometry.coordinates[0]` and `feature.geometry.coordinates[1]` to be able to read the coordinates for the marker.

[This is an example of what I am trying to do.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144691/google-maps-multiple-marker-from-extern-json) As I understand it, it's the same thing by reading into the properties of the JSON (in this case, a var) object.

I have Google Maps and the Stamen Toner base map loaded before the JavaScript fires so I don't think it's not having the div loaded before I call the JSON but I could definitely be wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Maryland Prisoner Map</title>
    <!--jQuery-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Google Maps API-->
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <!--Stamen Basemaps-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.stamen.com/js/tile.stamen.js?v1.3.0"></script>
    <!--CSS-->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--JavaScript-->
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body class="page-wrap">
    <div>
        <h1 id="header">Maryland Prisoner Map</h1>
        <p></p>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <footer class="site-footer">Thank you for checking out my website!</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    #header {
    text-align: center;
}

#map {
    height: 800px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px 2px gray;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
    margin-bottom: -90px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
    height: 90px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var layer = "toner-lite";
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.290385, -76.612189),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: layer,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [layer]
        }
    });
    map.mapTypes.set(layer, new google.maps.StamenMapType(layer));
    //Get some JSON
    $.getJSON("JSON/County.geojson", function(data) {
        console.log("The JSON has been sought");
        $.each(data, function(i, data) {
            createMarker(data);
        });
    });

    function createMarker(data) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.feature.geometry.coordinates[0], data.features.geometry.coordinates[1]),
            map: map,
            title: data.features.name
        });
    }
});
```

Sample JSON:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 1, "Address": "14300 McMullen Highway SW", "City": "Cumberland", "State": "MD", "Zip_Code": 21502, "Type": "Detention Center", "Agency_Nam": "Allegany County Detention Center", "County": "Allegany" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -78.823195987258302, 39.598971947812366 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 2, "Address": "131 Jennifer Road", "City": "Annapolis", "State": "MD", "Zip_Code": 21401, "Type": "Detention Center", "Agency_Nam": "Anne Arundel County Detention Center", "County": "Anne Arundel" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -76.530041483218611, 38.988903980495373 ] } }, . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more than one issue with your code:

1. (the one that is generating the error in the title) The GeoJson is not in the format your code is expecting.  You want to process the array of features (not the top level feature collection object)

   ```
   $.each(geoJsonData.features, function (i, data) {
       createMarker(data);
   });
   ```
2. the coordinates are a property of the feature (which is now `data`)
3. You are processing the latitude and longitude backwards.  coordinates[1] is latitude, coordinates[0] is longitude:

   ```
   function createMarker(data) {
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.geometry.coordinates[1], data.geometry.coordinates[0]),
           map: map,
           title: data.properties.Agency_Nam
       });
   }
   ```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vjqux9Lr/5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var layer = "toner-lite";
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.290385, -76.612189),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: layer,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [layer]
    }
  });
  map.mapTypes.set(layer, new google.maps.StamenMapType(layer));
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  //Get some JSON
  // $.getJSON("JSON/County.geojson", function(data) {
  console.log("The JSON has been sought");
  $.each(geoJsonData.features, function(i, data) {
    createMarker(data);
  });
  // });

  function createMarker(data) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.geometry.coordinates[1], data.geometry.coordinates[0]),
      map: map,
      title: data.properties.Agency_Nam
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
});

var geoJsonData = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },

  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "OBJECTID": 1,
      "Address": "14300 McMullen Highway SW",
      "City": "Cumberland",
      "State": "MD",
      "Zip_Code": 21502,
      "Type": "Detention Center",
      "Agency_Nam": "Allegany County Detention Center",
      "County": "Allegany"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-78.823195987258302, 39.598971947812366]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "OBJECTID": 2,
      "Address": "131 Jennifer Road",
      "City": "Annapolis",
      "State": "MD",
      "Zip_Code": 21401,
      "Type": "Detention Center",
      "Agency_Nam": "Anne Arundel County Detention Center",
      "County": "Anne Arundel"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-76.530041483218611, 38.988903980495373]
    }
  }]
};
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#header {
  text-align: center;
}
#map {
  height: 85%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px 2px gray;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -90px;
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer,
.page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 90px;
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.stamen.com/js/tile.stamen.js?v1.3.0"></script>
<div style="height:100%; width: 100%">
  <h1 id="header">Maryland Prisoner Map</h1>

  <p></p>
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
<footer class="site-footer">Thank you for checking out my website!</footer>
```

Comment: Why did you change

 `$.getJSON("JSON/County.geojson", function(data) {
        console.log("The JSON has been sought");
        $.each(data, function(i, data) {
            createMarker(data);
        });
    });` 


to

   $.each(geoJsonData.features, function(i, data) {
    createMarker(data);
  });`

including greying out the `$.getJSON` ?

And is `$.each(geoJsonData` something that the browser would recognize natively with JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Because you didn't provide a publicly available link to your GeoJson and the problem was not with loading the GeoJson, but with parsing it.

Comment: Ah ok, I could still do County (don't have the JSON online anywhere). 


Why did you put features in the parameter instead of `geoJsonData.features` rather than `data.features.geometry.coordinates` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, what "parameter"?

Comment: Why did you put `features` where you put it?

Comment: Are you asking why I put `geoJsonData.features` in this line: `$.each(geoJsonData.features, function(i, data) {`?  That is addressed in #1 of my answer.

Comment: No, I am not asking that. I am asking why you put `.features` in that line rather than later on where I had it in `data.features.geometry.coordinates`.

Comment: `data.features` is the array of features that you need to iterate through `data.features.geometry.coordinates` is not valid, you need to specify which element of the array to access (i.e. `data.features[0].geometry.coordinates` )

Comment: If I have the geojson in a separate file can I do `var data = County.geojson` in order to do `data.features` ?