# Marker not showing in google map for external JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a `crime_map.txt` file to be shown on a map. 
My `HTML` :

```
<div id="crime-map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
```

And Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    initialize();

    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center    : new google.maps.LatLng(26.152891, 91.781718)
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("crime-map"),mapOptions);
    }
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("crime_points.txt", function(json1) {
      $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng); 
        // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            title: data.title
        });
        marker.setMap(map);

        //console.log(marker);
      });
    });
});
</script>
```

And the `crime_map.txt` :

```
[{
    "title": "Stockholm",
    "lat": 26.17189,
    "lng": 91.7645983333333,
    "description": "Stockholm is the capital and the largest city of Sweden and constitutes the most populated urban area in Scandinavia with a population of 2.1 million in the metropolitan area (2010)"
  },
  {
    "title": "Oslo",
    "lat": 26.1717463,
    "lng": 91.7645724,
    "description": "Oslo is a municipality, and the capital and most populous city of Norway with a metropolitan population of 1,442,318 (as of 2010)."
  },
  {
    "title": "Copenhagen",
    "lat": 26.1444045,
    "lng": 91.7860568,
    "description": "Copenhagen is the capital of Denmark and its most populous city, with a metropolitan population of 1,931,467 (as of 1 January 2012)."
  }]
```

But when I run the code, the map is shown but can't see any markers there ! Whats wrong going on ?
REF :[StackOvrflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144691/google-maps-multiple-marker-from-extern-json)

EDITED TO :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    initialize();

    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center    : new google.maps.LatLng(26.152891, 91.781718)
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("crime-map"),mapOptions);
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(map);
    $.getJSON("crime_points.txt", function(json1) {
      $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng); 
        // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            title: data.title
        });
        marker.setMap(map);

        //console.log(marker);
      });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it a single script , you can not declare a variable and get it from another script . based on your code structure , this is the most close solution i made for you . try it let me know if this works .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
initialize();

var map;

function initialize() 
{
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center    : new google.maps.LatLng(26.152891, 91.781718)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("crime-map"),mapOptions);


$.getJSON("crime_points.txt", function(json1) {
  $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng); 

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        title: data.title
    });
    marker.setMap(map);

    //console.log(marker);
  });
});


}
</script>
```

here is the live code example using your json , have a look [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nurfarazi/uv5zz9w6/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haved edited the code( see my question) , but I can't see the markers ! :(

Comment: i edited the answer with live demo , i hope that will serve you well, and congratulation on 1k reputation